# Процедура c циклом на pl/pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Подскажите реализацию следующего алгоритма на **pg/plsql**.
Сам алгоритм придумал, но не знаю как его реализовать в рамках postgres

Есть две таблицы

```
create table organisation(
    id int4, 
    full_name varchar(512), 
    name varchar(255), 
    short_name varchar(255), 
    activity_id int4
    )

create table contract(
    id int4, 
    registry_number varchar(30), 
    provider_id int4
    )
```

В таблице организаций есть дублирующие организации, к которым привязаны контракты в таблице контрактов(id из organisation прописан в поле provider_id в таблице contract).
Нужно поменять привязку контрактов с дублирующих организаций на оригинальные.

Найти все дублирующие организации в таблице organisation:

```
select * from organisation o 
where activity_id is null and name is null and short_name = ''
```

Далее в цикле по каждой записи из выборки выше сделать следующие действия:

1. Найти и запомнить id оригинальной организации(origin_org_id) для дублирующей организации (dubl_org_id) текущий итерации (у них совпадает поле full_name, но оно в разных регистрах):

```
select id from organisation o 
where lower (full_name) = lower (<< full_name current iteration with dubl_org_id >>) and name is not null 
order by id asc
```

2. В таблице контрактов в записи, которые привязаны к dubl_org_id текущей итерации в поле provider_id проставляем origin_org_id:

```
update contract set provider_id = origin_org_id
where provider_id = dubl_org_id
```

Comment: А зачем тут pl/pgsql и какие то циклы. Это делается одним запросом update с join с выборкой возвращающей origin_org_id для каждого dubl_org_id. А это в свою очередь делается средствами стандартного sql не зависящего от того какая именно у вас СУБД. (ну если сделать какие нибудь дополнительные допущения вроде того, что для дублирующихся организаций брать за origin_org_id например минимальный id среди всех дублей)

Comment: *В таблице организаций есть дублирующие организации* Укажите точно выражение, которое определяет, являются записи дубликатами или нет. *поменять привязку контрактов с дублирующих организаций на оригинальные* Укажите точно выражение, которое определяет, является запись оригиналом или дубликатом.

Comment: @Akina, дублирующие записи удовлетворяют следующим условиям (where activity_id is null and name is null and short_name = '' ), указал это в вопросе.

Comment: @Mike не понимаю как это можно сделать когда у нас есть много разных организаций и для каждой нужно проделать несколько действий, прежде чем сделать update. Можете написать сам скрипт, того что имеете ввиду, или схематично написать с использованием псевдокода?

Comment: *дублирующие записи удовлетворяют следующим условиям (where activity_id is null and name is null and short_name = '' )* То есть если указанные три поля соответствуют этим условиям, в поле `id` лежат значения 1 и 2, а в поле `full_name` значения `'Рога и копыта'` и `'Пупкин и Ко'` - то это дубликаты. Верно?

Comment: @Akina да, все записи, удовлетворяющие этим условиям - дублирующие организации. В случае с вашим примером получается мы нашли дубли организаций 'Рога и копыта' и 'Пупкин и Ко'

Comment: :facepalm: нет слов...

Comment: Где тут дубли, если 'Рога и копыта' всего одна в БД и других с таким же названием нет, она к чему дублем является ?

Comment: @Mike Есть две оригинальные организации 'Рога и копыта' и 'Пупкин и Ко' и у каждой организации есть по дублю, удовлетворяющие условиям, которые я описал в вопросе.

Comment: откуда вы знаете что эти дубли есть ? а вдруг их нет